# Execute parallel tests in Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I need to execute parallel tests in Jenkins (I have 200 tests done with Selenium Webdriver under Eclipse), I've tried to do it with the following code in my pom.xml file  with no luck:

```
<plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
       <configuration>
              <parallel>classes</parallel>
              <threadCount>5</threadCount>
         </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

This code works at the beginning (it loads 5 tests), but then, it doesn't end fine, it gets stopped. I don't know why. However, if I put the plugin "maven-surefire-plugin" as "dependency" and not as "plugin", my test (only one at a time) works fine.

How could I get the parallel tests??

Thanks so much!!!!

Comment: Which testing framework you're using? How do you build your project in jekins? What do you mean by 'stuck'?

Comment: Stuck= stopped, and finally fail. I build my project by "mvn test" from Jenkins. I use Eclipse to write my java code to create my tests (Selenium Webdriver).

Comment: As I understand you're using testNG? Have you tried to execute suite locally by providing parallel params in suite?

Comment: @Mikhail I'm very new in this topic, I don't understand what you mean, sorry